# Tkinter app runs on windows but doesn't open window on raspberry pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I'm writing a tkinter python app that is meant to run on a raspberry pi. When I run the code from the build in IDE on the pi it runs fine and the window opens up, same on IDLE on my windows PC,  however when I try and run the program from the command line, it does nothing when I hit enter on the command `python3 filename`. As well as this, when I enter the python shell from the command line I am able to get a tkinter window to appear using `root = Tk()`, so I cannot figure out why my program won't run.

Comment: do you have a `if __name__ == '__main__':...` in your python file?. To run your app you usually need to have a [`__main__` block](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html)

Comment: no. Should I, and if so where?

Comment: I added a link of how `__main__` works on the first comment. Ultimately you need to have it at the end of your code and whatever command you use to run the whole thing should be placed in there. So if `root = Tk()` is a command then do `if __name__ == '__main__': root=Tk()`

Comment: i'll try this, sorry to bother you but can you explain why my method works on IDLE and other IDEs just not on the command prompt?

Comment: np. It depends. How did you run it in the IDLE? did you just run it line by line or did you run the whole script at once?

Comment: i ran the entire script at once with a mainloop() command at the end.

Comment: yea sorry. there could be different reasons behind your issue but I am assuming if you are not running into any errors when you do `python3 filename.py` then either the code ran and the window din't show up or some configs on the IDLE are missing outside of it. Hopefully someone had a similar issue and can speak to it

Comment: yeah hopefully, thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now fixed this myself so posting the answer in case anyone needs it. My `mainloop()` function was actually `MainPage.mainloop()` which for some reason stopped the window from opening from the command prompt...